User exists in the Database, but returns null when called
//schema.prisma

model User {
  id                        String                      @id @default(uuid())
  email                     String
  firstName                 String                      
  profileImage              String?           
  favoriteIds               String[]                      
  createdAt                 DateTime                    @default(now())
}
//api/auth/creation/route.ts

import { prismadb } from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { auth, currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  const { userId } = auth();
  const user = await currentUser();

  if (!userId || user === null || !user.id) {
    return new NextResponse("Unauthenticated", { status: 401 });
  }

  let dbUser = await prismadb.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: user.id,
    },
  });

  if (!dbUser) {
    dbUser = await prismadb.user.create({
      data: {
        email: user.primaryEmailAddress?.emailAddress ?? "",
        firstName: user.firstName ?? "",
        id: user.id,
        profileImage:
          user.imageUrl ?? `https://avatar.vercel.sh/${user.firstName}`,
      },
   });
 }
  return NextResponse.redirect(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL!);
}

//actions/getCurrentUser.tsx

import { prismadb } from "@/lib/prismadb";
import { currentUser } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

export async function getSession() {
  return await currentUser(); 
}

export default async function getCurrentUser() {
  try {
    const session = await getSession();

    if (!session?.primaryEmailAddress?.emailAddress) {
      return null;
    }

    const currentUser = await prismadb.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: session.id,
        email: session.primaryEmailAddress.emailAddress,
      },
    });

    if (!currentUser) {
      return null;
    }

    return currentUser;
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
}

//api/favorites/[elementSlug]/route.ts
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { prismadb } from "@/lib/prismadb";
import getCurrentUser from "@/actions/getCurrentUser";

type Props = {
  elementSlug?: string;
};

export async function POST(request: Request, { params }: { params: Props }) {
  const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

  if (!currentUser) {
    return NextResponse.error();
  }

  const { elementSlug } = params;

  if (!elementSlug || typeof elementSlug !== "string") {
    throw new Error("Invalid Slug");
  }

  let favoriteIds = [...(currentUser.favoriteIds || [])];

  favoriteIds.push(elementSlug);

  const user = await prismadb.user.update({
    where: {
      id: currentUser.id,
    },
    data: {
      favoriteIds,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(user); 
}

export async function DELETE(request: Request, { params }: { params: Props }) {
  const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();

  if (!currentUser) {
    return NextResponse.error();
  }

  const { elementSlug } = params;

  if (!elementSlug || typeof elementSlug !== "string") {
    throw new Error("Invalid Slug");
  }

  let favoriteIds = [...(currentUser.favoriteIds || [])];

  favoriteIds = favoriteIds.filter((slug) => slug !== elementSlug);

  const user = await prismadb.user.update({
    where: {
      id: currentUser.id,
    },
    data: {
      favoriteIds,
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(user);
}

//hooks/useFavorite.ts
import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import { useToast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast";
import { User } from "@prisma/client";

type Props = {
  elementSlug: string;
  currentUser?: User | null;
};

export const useFavorite = ({ elementSlug, currentUser }: Props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const hasFavorited = useMemo(() => {
    const list = currentUser?.favoriteIds || [];

    return list.includes(elementSlug);
  }, [currentUser, elementSlug]);

  const toggleFavorite = useCallback(
    async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
      e.stopPropagation();

      if (!currentUser) {
        router.push("/sign-in");
      }

      try {
        let request;

        if (hasFavorited) {
          request = () => axios.delete(`/api/favorites/${elementSlug}`);
        } else {
          request = () => axios.post(`/api/favorites/${elementSlug}`);
        }

        await request();
        router.refresh();
        toast({ title: "Success" });
      } catch (error) {
        toast({ variant: "destructive", title: "Oops! Something went wrong." });
      }
    },
    [currentUser, hasFavorited, elementSlug, router]
  );

  return {
    hasFavorited,
    toggleFavorite,
  };

};
//heart-button.tsx

"use client";

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { User } from "@prisma/client";
import { Heart } from "lucide-react";
import {
  Tooltip,
  TooltipContent,
  TooltipProvider,
  TooltipTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/tooltip";
import React from "react";
import { useFavorite } from "@/hooks/useFavorite";

type Props = {
  elementSlug: string;
  currentUser?: User | null;
};
export const HeartButton = ({ elementSlug, currentUser }: Props) => {
  const { hasFavorited, toggleFavorite } = useFavorite({
    elementSlug,
    currentUser,
  });
  return (
    <TooltipProvider>
      <Tooltip delayDuration={200}>
        <TooltipTrigger asChild>
          <div
            onClick={toggleFavorite}
            className="relative hover:opacity-80 transition cursor-pointer w-8 h-8 bg- 
    white shadow-sm border rounded-lg flex items-center justify-center"
          >
            <Heart
              className={cn(
                "w-5 h-5 absolute hover:fill-rose-500 transition-colors duration-500",
                hasFavorited ? "fill-rose-500" : "fill-primary/50"
              )}
              fill="black"
              stroke="none"
            />
          </div>
        </TooltipTrigger>
        <TooltipContent>
          <p className="text-sm">Save</p>
        </TooltipContent>
      </Tooltip>
    </TooltipProvider>
  );
};

I'm building this app using Nextjs, Prisma, and Clerk, and I came across a problem in the useFavorite file when I realized that I am not getting a user, and every time I clicked on the HeartButton, I was always sent back to the sign-in page. Whenever an account signs up, the Clerk user is directly created in my database, with all the information, and when I click on the HeartButton, the favoriteIds updates, but only when I post(it doesn't delete if I click on the button for a second time).
So the currentUser?: User | null seems always to return null, even though I have a user in my database. I have been trying to understand the problem for hours and nothing. There is something I can't see.
Your help will be appreciated and welcomed. Thanks in advance.
